# All but one test class not running Visual Studio 2019

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2019

I'm attempting to do unit and integration tests for my application.

I'm using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

The generated class that I refactored works just fine and all the tests run.

I have added additional classes to the project and none of the tests in those files are detected by the test explorer.

[As you can see, DatabaseConnectionTests is running just fine but CourseInformation tests isn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWy2O.png)

I have checked to make sure the test methods have '[TestMethod]' above them, they return void and have no parameters just like the methods in DatabaseConnectionTests that run.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite embarrassing, but after looking at the image, I realised my classes were not public.

Going to leave this up in case anyone else overlooks this simple mistake.